# For loop in js log another index

Tags: javascript, jquery

I did something like the below shown code:

```js
for(var is = 1; is <= 10; is++) {
  $('#add1-' + is).click(function () {
    console.log(is);
  });
}
```

When I click on button id=`add1-1` the console log show that is=11
and same in `add1-2`, index name `is`= 11
What can fix that?

Comment: it because `is  variable` last value is `11` after loop is completed.Also you are binding event inside loop, which is very bad idea. Use type attribute selector

Comment: @AlivetoDie but I do the click function`s in the loop

Comment: @AlivetoDie why its bad idea? you have another usage?

Comment: John i have added an answer

Answer (score 0):

If you **really** want to do a loop, you're gonna have to do something like this:

```js
for (var is = 1; is <= 10; is++) {
  $('#add1-' + is).on('click', {is}, function(e) {
    console.log(e.data.is);
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="add1-1">click me 1</div>
<div id="add1-2">click me 2</div>
<div id="add1-3">click me 3</div>
```

However it would be much better to do something like this:

```js
$('[data-is]').on('click', function(e) {
  console.log($(this).data('is'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-is="1" id="add1-1">click me 1</div>
<div data-is="2" id="add1-2">click me 2</div>
<div data-is="3" id="add1-3">click me 3</div>
```

`data-` attributes let you bind data to elements and are way more appropriate than using IDs themselves for this purpose. [Read about them in the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes).

Comment: Thanks, but I have a question: what is it mean data-is?

Comment: @John I've edited my post to give the idea (also link to the docs to learn more).

Comment: @John  can you show me the button HTML structure what you have. Add it in your question

Comment: @John and Jeto i will still say that binding event inside loop is bad idea.Apply second approach or mine one

Comment: @AlivetoDie That's what I implied in the answer.

Comment: Why its bad Idea? @AlivetoDie

Comment: because if one event binding can handle multiple button click then why to bind click event for each-one separately?jquery ment to make things easier not complex